# How to use a generic type with `typeof Node<T>`?

Tags: java, typescript, generics

Let's say we have some Java `Node`, `StringNode` and `NodeFactory` classes:

```java
public class Node<T> {
    private T value;

    public void init(T value){
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public class StringNode extends Node<String> {}

public class NodeFactory {
    public static <T> Node<T> createNode(Class<? extends Node<T>> nodeClass, T value) throws Exception {
        Node<T> node = nodeClass.getConstructor().newInstance();
        node.init(value);
        return node;
    }
}
```

So `NodeFactory.createNode(StringNode.class, "value1");` would create a `StringNode` with the value: `"value1"`.

How could I write such a factorymethod in typescript?

I tried to write a factorymethod in typescript:

```js
public static createNode<T>(NodeClass: typeof Node<T>, value: T): Node<T> {
    const node = new NodeClass();
    node.init(value);
    return node;
}
```

but does not accept `typeof Node<T>` generic types. So I tried putting in the method's type arguments:

```js
public static createNode<T, N extends Node<T>>(NodeClass: typeof N, value: T): Node<T> {
```

But the compiler does not accept that either: `typeof N`: `TS2693: 'N' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here`

Is there a typesafe way to write such a factorymethod in typescript?

Comment: This syntax `typeof Node<T>` will be available in several months. See [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47607) PR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic parameter of a class applies to to *instances* and not the static class itself. And the `value` is also for instances. So `NodeClass` needs to be a "newable" type, that returns an instance with the right generic.

That means this will work:

```
function createNode<T>(NodeClass: { new (): MyNode<T> }, value: T): MyNode<T> {
    const node = new NodeClass();
    node.init(value)
    return node;
}
```

Testing:

```
// good
const a = createNode(StringNode, "asd")
const b = createNode(NumberNode, 123)
const c = createNode(FunctionNode, () => 'hello world')
const d = createNode(MyNode, true) // MyNode<boolean>

// error, as expected
const bad = createNode(StringNode, 123)
```

`createNode(MyNode, true)` is a nice bonus. Typescript picks up `T` from the second argument, and puts it in the `NodeClass` for you.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=1&pln=26&pc=40#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeA5A9gEwKYB4AqA+aA3gFDTQBuYIArugFzTbQA+0AdlSCNALxschES0AJathAFwAUFanQYBKQkNLiAFsIgA6GTR7lKNIQF8iJoqEgwAyuIBOogOYoM0dAA9x6VqhgJnWCDtHfAITCyhoRCoAWwAjdFt-Vw8vHzgkNCx2OISQsPAIgDEqVmBxYWRWJPdPb18MjExJRW58MmRhVDzBADMSsorWaGBbdDBPfxxcSX8AYQKIegI2dAB3aGb6P0yp6CMAGn1Zemx5LYasPCVSUmBKwLZMvVY1yMz5y2aAbmVHjE1RBJpAZ0PJfqNxFRbENWJkfmYAPQI6AOZBocz3cTQMB6EZjCaZSQ2eysJyZQ4AIkgqApYLurAesVxo3G6H8Mxi8US5OgAEYAEwAZjpmOGzPxbMJxVK5Uq-kOzR4+AA5Kp0JxkNBVshbCBUMqRQysahxaz2dsMIc7DRFEj0pNYmiQGNWLhBHaErYdYdIMkAA7oMroVAYo3QWJgE28PFmwnExzyvlC+RAA)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
public static createNode<N extends { new(): Node<T> }, T>(NodeClass: N, value: T): Node<T> {
```

apparently I just needed N to implement a interface with a `new(): Node<T>` method (or constructor).

Comment: One difference between my answer and this answer is that the `N` generic here is not required. Capturing `T` alone is sufficient.